how to get list of values from nested panda dictionary and insert it in to a column
I have a nested dictionary which looks like following:
  {'NSE_FO:NIFTY28DEC21000CE': {'ohlc': None,
  'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 0},
    {'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1}],
   'sell': [{'quantity': 0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 0},
    {'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1}]},
  },
 'NSE_FO:NIFTY28DEC24000CE': {'ohlc': None,
  'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 1, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 0},
    {'quantity': 1, 'price': 1.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 2, 'price': 2.0, 'orders': 1}],
   'sell': [{'quantity': 0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 0},
    {'quantity': 3, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 4, 'price': 4.0, 'orders': 1}]},
  },
 'NSE_FO:NIFTY28DEC28000PE': {'ohlc': {'open': 0.0,
   'high': 0.0,
   'low': 0.0,
   'close': 0.0},
  'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 250, 'price': 1040.05, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 4, 'price': 1.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 2, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1}],
   'sell': [{'quantity': 0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 3, 'price': 3.0, 'orders': 1},
    {'quantity': 4, 'price': 4.0, 'orders': 1}]},
  }}

i want to extract the 1st price value from depth->buy->price of each NSE_FO:NIFTY28DEC24000CE' without using loop and insert it into a new column. is it possible?
desired output :
0.0
3.0
1040.05

             


No, it's not possible, since you be have a python object you have to loop on way or another.

out = [x['depth']['buy'][0]['price'] for x in dic.values()]
